# Can I apply for UK Spouse visa by providing 6 months of payslips even though I don't get fixed salary every month?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, spouses

Hi my Girlfriend is a British Citizen and I'm from India. I met her during my student visa and we been together for more than 3 years in UK. We tried to apply for spouse visa with all the documents but UKVI rejected because financial requirement was not met even though they mentioned we have a genuine relationship. They asked me to do a voluntary return to India and then apply from there. I came back to India on January 2019. Since my girlfriend is a full time masters student she couldn't focus on work and studies at the same time. Since she works in zero hour contract, She doesn't get fixed salary every month but works with a same employer for more than 5 years. My question is that if we are to apply using a 6 months payslip with a average of 1550+ every month can we still satisfy the financial requirement? I consulted a solicitor but he says we cannot because there is no fixed salary every month. 
   She came this April for 2 weeks and ever since then we haven't met each other. Nearly 6 months now, we both get sad and depressed for not being close together. Below is my partners 12 months payslip including tax. Please let me know is there any other option.

Sep-18  266.98
Oct-18  1432.38
Nov-18  2178.52
Dec-18  1126.26
Jan-19  861.91
Feb-19  2042.22
Mar-19  2196.15
Apr-19  326.2
May-19  337.27
Jun-19  1950.13
Jul-19  1802.18
Aug-19  1561.64

Answer (score 3):

Yes, so long as you can demonstrate the income via payslips or other documentation such as a P60, and that income meets the threshold (£18,600 for a couple without children), you should be fine as the [guidance](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/826340/Appendix-FM-1-7-Financial-Requirement-ext_1.pdf) does not require a fixed income per month.

The real issue you have is that the income you demonstrate in your post does not meet the threshold...